# Error while using Google Analytics Reporting API

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-java-client

I am trying to use the `Google Analytics Reporting API v4` (java) but while trying to use their sample code available in https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java

Having build errors, I have added below dependency in my pom.xml
But not sure which dependency to add to fix the error

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.exhaust`

Even after adding guava dependency version 20.0 still having the error.

Added dependencies:->

```
          <!--Google Analytics Reporting API dependency-->
           <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-api-services-analyticsreporting</artifactId>
                <version>v4-rev20200902-1.31.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.31.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-api-client-gson</artifactId>
                <version>1.30.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                 <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                 <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                 <version>2.12.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.38.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>20.0</version>
            </dependency>
```